# How to submit form as GET method when it is initially loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a page that is loaded from jQuery ajax, this page has a form on it that needs to be submitted with the GET method. When I click the submit button nothing happens. I'm guessing this is because the form needs to be initialized somehow after being loaded by ajax?

This is what I have in my jQuery code

```
$('body').on('click','#dbRecords',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load('/?url=databases/records.php');
});
```

The records.php page has a simple form as such

```
<form name="" method="get" action="/databases/records/" id="searchForm" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="sub" id="searchSub" />
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to clicking something with an id of `dbRecords`, but you have nothing in your form with that ID.

Comment: there is a button with an id="dbRecords" that when clicked loads the records.php page, once records.php is loaded the regular form using get does not work.

Comment: If the HTML of the form is showing, the HTML is 'initialised' by the browser. Maybe some JavaScript is preventing the form from submitting? Can you show the page where this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the form tag on the first line. Change it to this:

```
<form name="" method="get" action="/databases/records/" id="searchForm">
```